# Gradle android native libs conflict error: More than one file was found with OS independent path

Tags: android, gradle

I have a problem with a Gradle dependency conflict.
The Gradle error is:

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libavcodec.so'

After some tests, I found that 2 of my project dependencies use ffmpeg libs.

I know that I can use `packageOptions` with `exclude` or `pickFirst` but I don't know if these 2 libs use the same version of ffmpeg.

Is there an option to tell gradle to keep the two versions?

Android studio version: 3.6-RC1,
Gradle version: 5.4.1

Thanks

Comment: i am also facing same issue did you find any solution?